# User specific views MVC

Tags: codeigniter, roles

I've some action buttons on a page. Then in my `CI controller` i've `functions` for each
  of them like `view, edit, new`.   Now all these functions have this `if else` block. Is this how
  you do it? Other patterns?

I'm using CI with mod. extension and have many controllers under several modules with
  this kind of functions.

```
if(hasPermission('view_all'))
{
   $this->model->queryAll()
   $this->load->view('all_layout')
}
else if(hasPermission('view_group'))
{
   $this->model->queryGroup()
   $this->load->view('group_layout');
} 
else {
   $this->model->querySingle()
   $this->load->view('single_layout');
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to write if block or how to use `controller functions` with `views` and `models`?

Comment: so my every function are going to have that `if else`?

Answer (score 0):

I would have written the same code using Switch Case & little tweak in hasPermission class

```
  $permission = getPermission() // It wud return 1 for view_all, 2 for view_group, 3 for single layout

  switch($permission){
     case 1:
       $this->model->queryAll();
       $this->load->view('all_layout');
       break;
     case 2:
       $this->model->queryGroup();
       $this->load->view('group_layout');
       break;
     default:
       $this->model->querySingle()
       $this->load->view('single_layout');
       break;
 }
```

I know this code doesn't decrease number of lines, but sometimes readability is more important then LOC :) I would like to see more improvisations